# Stepping down from the Moderator position

Tags: support, moderation

Hello noble community,

It is with great respect and deep appreciation, that I would like to request a dismissal from this position of Moderator of Buddhism Q&A.

It was a big privilege and undeserved honor to play a key part of this community in its initial stages. While my level of insight was barely enough to fill the void of guidance we had in the beginning, it is definitely not at a level to make positive difference now, when community is so much more mature.

ChrisW is truly the heart and soul of the moderation team, and Lanka is a wise and noble partner - whose combined experience and grace at handling issues far exceeds anything I can pretend to possess.

I am humbled by the fact that you let me stay a moderator for so long, without actually requiring me to fulfill much of the moderation duty. I feel like I'm occupying this place as a way of community tradition or inertia - but believe me, there is definitely more than one person capable of doing this job way better than I did (or rather, did not).

Rest assured that I will remain a member - definitely a reader and upvoter, and occasionally an answerer, although it is clear to me that much more practice is required before I can say anything useful again.

Thanks everyone, but especially my dearest friends ChrisW and Lanka - and I will see you online.

Comment: Thank you for your commitment Andrei. Moderation aside, I think It's unfortunate to not see your participation as frequent as it once was.

Comment: Andrei, "it is definitely not at a level to make positive difference now", just remarke that: my person does not see that but simply the opposite and also likes to remark, that Andrei, his kind and approaches are for sure a good ingredient for this place. After all moderator is not a teacher or content-giver but merely a admirable guide who keeps others from mistakes. Such requires wisdom and not a little anything else. With this distancing here by words and thiughts even perfect in being not a part of a team and struggle with such. Maybe some thiught to consider. Anyway best wishes & Sadhu!

Comment: Sadhu for you efforts and future endeavors

Comment: "I am humbled by the fact that you let me stay a moderator for so long, without actually requiring me to fulfill much of the moderation duty. I feel like I'm occupying this place as a way of community tradition or inertia - but believe me, there is definitely more than one person capable of doing this job way better than I did (or rather, did not)." This is really a great paragraph but human mind is not staying still, so unfourtunately this decision is changed.

Comment: Yeah, no one else stepped up and they had to ask me back.

Answer (score 5):

First of all thank you for your kind words and your great effort as a Moderator on Buddhism SE. I think you have an enourmous amount of intellectual, scholarly and practical knowledge which your posts clearly show. I'm happy that you will  continue to be a user on the site as we really enjoy and learn from your insightful answers.
Also I don't think there would have been a Community if you were not participating as a moderator in the early days of the site.

For me personally I've experienced that when I was in doubt about moderation issues/policies you were there to step in and give a nuanced and solid solution. Thank you for that. It helped me grow and learn in this field and to become a more experienced moderator.

Regarding answers on Buddhism SE, you have a special way of writing that is pinpoint on-topic and filled with insights. I look forward to read more of your posts in the future.

For now I'll say thank you for the cooperation and time as a Moderator. It has been great to work with you and you will be missed on the Team.

Warm regards,

Lanka

Comment: Not for sure... just a few are able to go on and leave the keys back inside. May there be nobody miss seldom possibilities, where ever there kusala path arises. Mudita.